# Converting a string to readable format in python

Tags: python, string, non-ascii-characters

What text format is this:
`\xe1\x984a\x82@Z\xb4\x85\xd0`
I would like to convert this to readable format. I attempted decoding with utf-16 but leads to error. Also encoding to ascii does not work.

Comment: Without knowing the encoding, you are not going to be able to convert it.

Comment: will you provide your error list?

Answer (score 0):

From My understanding `\xe1\x984a\x82@Z\xb4\x85\xd0` is look like bytes stream.

so you can convert in readable format like this.

```
>>> b'\xe1\x984a\x82@Z\xb4\x85\xd0'.decode('utf-8','ignore')
'4a@Z'
```

you byte stream string also give the output in integer format like this.

```
>>> int.from_bytes(b'\xe1\x984a\x82@Z\xb4\x85\xd0', byteorder='big', signed=True)
-143585681428579525294640
```

for more you can visit [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html) and [here](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/unicode.html#python-s-unicode-support).

Comment: Not the desired result. Also, when I encode to ascii: 
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe1 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)

Comment: What is your desired output?